# How to use the RETURNING clause to insert into two tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-returning

I don't understand how to use `RETURNING`, e.g. how to get the actual value "in my hands" for next steps. Assume, I have two tables:

```
create table "actors" (
  id_act serial not null primary key,
  first_name text not null,
  last_name text not null
);
create table movies (
  id_mov serial not null primary key,
  act_id integer not null
);
```

Now I add an actor:

```
INSERT INTO actors (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Tom', 'Hanks');
```

and immediately after that, I'd like to use that new actor's-ID to insert a movie:

```
INSERT INTO movies(###);
```

How can I use `RETURNING` to use it instead of my placeholder ###?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need PL/pgSQL to use `RETURNING`, this can be used in plain SQL as well.

But for the problem you have, you need neither, because you can use `currval()` from the sequence backing `actors.id` to get the last generated `id`:

```
INSERT INTO actors (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Tom', 'Hanks');
INSERT INTO movies(act_id) values 
(currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('actors', 'act_id')));
```

If you really want to use RETURNING, you can use a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with new_actor as (
  INSERT INTO actors (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Tom', 'Hanks')
  returning id_act
)
insert into movies (act_id)
select id_Act
from new_actor;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=25cdfea3d6b73d3999a908c5eeea8ea9)

Comment: Thank you, but ...

I Issued five times
INSERT INTO actors (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Tom', 'Hanks');
id_act now is = 5
After that I issued
INSERT INTO movies(act_id) values (lastval());
and assumed to see 5 as act_id, but it is always the highest ID of Movies, not the latest from Actors

Comment: the with .. version produces an SQL-Error: returning id;  at or near ";"

Comment: @StOMicha: I had a wrong `;` inside the CTE. And you are right `lastval()` doesn't work because `movies` has a serial column as well. see my edit

Comment: Thanks a lot, the new with... looks good

is there any way, to get that ID into a variable for other usages?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the RETURNING clause in the INSERT statement to store the returned value in another variable.

Example:

```
create or replace procedure insert_rows()
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
 v_id_act int;
begin
INSERT INTO actors (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Tom', 'Hanks') RETURNING id_act INTO v_id_act;
INSERT INTO movies(act_id) values (v_id_act);
end;
$$;
CREATE PROCEDURE

call insert_rows();
CALL

select * from actors;
 id_act | first_name | last_name 
--------+------------+-----------
      1 | Tom        | Hanks
(1 row)

select * from movies;
 id_mov | act_id 
--------+--------
      1 |      1
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you, but ...
I issued 

the above CREATES, 

declare v_id_act int;

INSERT INTO actors (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Tom', 'Hanks') RETURNING id_act INTO v_id_act;

and this results in a SQL-Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTO"

Comment: I have displayed the output of statements execution with `psql`: you only need to run the `create or replace ... $$;`(11 lines) in psql *in one go*. I don't understand how you can have a syntax error. Which tool are you using to run the statements ?

Comment: I used dBeaver. I don't want the procedure; here [link] (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-insert/) I found a description, please refer to the last chapter "Get the last insert id": All I want now is to get that value "8" in my hands for further storage and usage.

Comment: What is your host programming language ? Maybe it's possible to retrieve using an host variable but I am not sure. If this is what you really want to do, ask a new question detailing this specific need and add the host language as question tag.